# How to move position for navigation text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create navigation bar but it won't align perfectly with the background in my html `body`. Here's what I've got so far:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="head-nav">
    <ul class="navigasi">
      <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PORTAL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FORUM</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigasi {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.navigasi li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.navigasi >li> a {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 29px;
}
```

I want to move the FACEBOOK, PORTAL, and FORUM  left or rightin order to align with each box. I've tried adding style in HTML like this:

```
<li><a style="left: 30px;" href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
```

But it won't work.
Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: use `position` and then use  `left` `right` for adjusting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want `left`, `right`, `top` or `bottom` to apply, give it a `position`, other than `static` (which is default):

```
<li><a style="left: 30px;position:relative;" href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a text-align property of left on .navigasi >li> a instead of giving it text-align: to right.

```
`.navigasi >li> a {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 29px;
}`
```